# pages number doesn't appear in the reference with using @book and .bib

Tags: bibliographies

I have the following reference

```
@book{2,
author    = "Sebastian Thrun and Wolfram Burgard and Dieter Fox",
title     = "Probabilistic Robotics",
publisher = "The MIT Press",
year      = "2006",
pages     = "309"
}
```

The output of this citation is

> Sebastian Thrun, Wolfram Burgard, and Dieter Fox. Probabilistic
>   Robotics. The MIT Press, 2006.

The problem is that the pages don't appear in the citation.

I'm using `.bib` as a plain text for holding the references as follows

`main.tex`

```
\documentclass[12p]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}


hhhhhh \cite{2}. 

\bibliography{references}{}
\bibliographystyle{plain}


\end{document}
```

`references.bib`

```
@book{2,
author    = "Sebastian Thrun and Wolfram Burgard and Dieter Fox",
title     = "Probabilistic Robotics",
publisher = "The MIT Press",
year      = "2006",
pages     = "309"
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you need the pages to be printed?  It's not very common that the pages of a whole book are used in bibliographies, since they don't serve much purpose.

Comment: `\bibliography{}` only takes a single argument as far as I know. Also, I don't know if it matters, but `\bibliographystyle` usually comes first. But @AlanMunn is right: entries for books don't usually include page numbers or the total number of pages.

Comment: @AlanMunn, no I don't really have to do it but what is the benefit of `pages` parameter if they are not included in the citation?

Comment: @CroCo some styles use `pages` for `book` entries; some styles don't. `plain` is one of the ones that doesn't.

Comment: @croco None of the major style guides (MLA, APA, Chicago) require pages for books, and I doubt if there are any journals in the natural sciences that require them either. I've only seen them used in very specialized contexts,  e.g. the bibliography item that accompanies a review of book in a journal.

Comment: @CroCo You cite *from* a bibliographic item, which in this case is a book. The bibliography is meant for making the reader able to retrieve the item. If you cite a particular page from a book, then the page number should be shown at the citation, not in the bibliography.

Comment: @egreg That depends on the subject area: in chemistry it is  common to give a reference to a book page or pages, and rather less common to reference a book as a whole.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is by design. If we take a look at `plain.bst` (the `\bibliographystyle` you're using), and find the section for `FUNCTION {book}`:

```
FUNCTION {book}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.bvolume output
      new.block
      format.number.series output
      new.sentence
      publisher "publisher" output.check
      address output
    }
    { new.block
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
}
```

There is no mention of `pages` anywhere in this function. Other entry types that use `pages` (such as `article`, `inproceedings`, etc.) all have some line similar to `format.pages output` which outputs the page number(s).

The `pages` parameter is still allowed and valid because, while the `plain` style doesn't use it, other styles can and do use it. So a given `.bib` file is usable with many different output styles.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `@inbook` entry type, it's proper for these kinda references.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I gave a similar one a while back to another question, and my answer was flagged for low quality. Had to expand it a little. I'll put it here so that if someone gets to your answer, through a google search or in some way, he could follow over to mine and see WHY it is the right answer...
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/373777/90297